# Java Serialization and references

Tags: java, serialization

Say I have a serialized class that is used to save the state of my game. This serialized text is stored in a text file. If I restart my computer,  reinstall  java, etc.  If I try to deserialize that text,  will it save everything that it is referenced? For the purpose of question,  assume the class has multiple ArrayList's of entitys and map elements.
Class -> Serialization - > text
Text - > Deserialization - > Class

Answer (score 1):

As long as the serialized classes don't change its definition, there won't be any problem. You may even move these serialized files into another OS which deserializes to the same classes definition and it will work with no problem (unless you use libraries specific to an OS, thus breaking portability).

Comment: It's possible to handle "old" class definitions by storing Generic objects and checking what type they are at runtime. Eg I store a list of "Vessels" not a list of "BattleShips". When it comes to run, I check if each Vessel is an InstanceOf BattleShip, and cast it accordingly. If I update BattleShip, I can save OldBattleShip and use the same InstanceOf technique to update it to the new standard while loading (typically you'd do this once, the first time the game updates) to keep things backwards compatible.

Comment: @JonStory yes, this can be done by implementing `writeObject` and `readObject` methods on the classes to serialize/deserialize, but I think that's outside of the scope of this question because OP is asking if the file can be deserialized even if OP uninstall and install JVM and not doing another changes.

Comment: I know, that's why I added it as a comment to your answer, not as a separate answer :) I'm adding information, not contradicting it.

Answer (score 0):

The serialized file will retain it's state regardless of whether or not you reinstall Java or restart your machine. It would be pretty useless otherwise: the point of serialization is to capture state in a persistent form for archival or transport in a fashion that can be to recreate that state later.

So, assuming the serialization method you are using originally saves all the references you care about, then you'll always be able to restore that object and all its references from that serialized data. Unless, perhaps, you try in five years using a new version of Java that no longer supports that serialization format or something.

Answer (score 0):

Are you about standart java serialization mechanism? Java serialization mechanism will serialize data to binary format, not text. Java guarantees serialization/deserialization between versions until you use standart java library. So yes in your case serialization will work good.

But, I don't sure that standart java serialization good for your purposes. Because:

- It's fully unreadable format.
- If you'll change language later you must fully reimplement saving format.

As alternative you can use some of xml serialization libraries for java. In this case, save file will have readable format (good for debugging).